# How to migrate from Internal Workbench API in RCP 4.4

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I work on a 3.7 RCP app that we are migrating to 4.4. and we have decided to use the 3.x-4.x compatibility layer. I used the following [article](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/06/18/migrating-from-eclipse-3-x-to-eclipse-4-e4/) as a blueprint, but even after adding the new Eclipse 4 required plugins mentioned in it, we are having issues with certain views not displaying when they are selected and some resizing issues with certain views and editors. The following is an excerpt from the article

> One important criteria for existing applications to work well on the compatibility layer is that they should not use any internal workbench API. Aside from this, there should be no source code changes required.

We make some usage of internal API calls in our code. My question is what do you substitute the calls to the internal workbench api with in Eclipse 4? And how do you know what areas of the app require such changes? Also, are there any other potential areas we need to change besides eliminating calls to the internal workbench? I am an RCP novice in this area, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no general answer about the internal APIs (other than you should not have been using them in the first place). You will have to ask individual questions about what alternative to use.

Comment: Greg. I understand. This is an issue I inherited that was created long before I came on board. For example, we have a class that implements the IPartListener2 interface and provides an implementation of the partOpened method which takes an IWorkbenchPartReference as a parameter. When debugging, the instance of IWorkbenchPartReference was org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference. Also, we make a call to IWorkbenchPage.setPartState which in turn makes a call to an internal workbench method. So I'm just trying to understand what's going on and what to replace these instances and calls with.

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question so that other people can find it in future.

Comment: I will do. Coming shortly